# Transformar colunas em linhas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Preciso transformar colunas de ocorrências em linhas para cada CPF.

Exemplo, tenho uma coluna em que as ocorrências de data e valor estão separadas em colunas, conforme abaixo:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CPF': [11111111111, 22222222222],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 1': ['01/01/2021', '15/02/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 1': [24.01, 36.97],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 2': ['22/03/2021', '02/09/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 2': [54.74, 96.7],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 3': ['04/05/2021', '06/11/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 3': [12.41, 15.85]
})
df
```

Saída:

| CPF | Data - Ocorrencia 1 | Valor - Ocorrencia 1 | Data - Ocorrencia 2 | Valor - Ocorrencia 2 | Data - Ocorrencia 3 | Valor - Ocorrencia 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | 01/01/2021 | 24.01 | 22/03/2021 | 54.74 | 04/05/2021 | 12.41 |
| 22222222222 | 15/02/2022 | 36.97 | 02/09/2022 | 96.70 | 06/11/2022 | 15.85 |

E preciso transformar no formato da tabela abaixo:

| CPF | Ocorrencia | Data | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | Ocorrencia 1 | 01/01/2021 | 24.01 |
| 11111111111 | Ocorrencia 2 | 22/03/2021 | 54.74 |
| 11111111111 | Ocorrencia 3 | 04/05/2021 | 12.41 |
| 22222222222 | Ocorrencia 1 | 15/02/2022 | 36.97 |
| 22222222222 | Ocorrencia 2 | 02/09/2022 | 96.70 |
| 22222222222 | Ocorrencia 3 | 06/11/2022 | 15.85 |

Ja tentei utilizar `pandas.melt` mas não fica no formato que preciso, desenvolvi um código enorme e que demora muito tempo que percorre as linhas uma a uma, separa em uma tabela temporária e depois faz um `merge`com a tabela principal, porém ele fica muito manual.

Pesquisei bastante e não achei nada nativo do `pandas` que fique no formato desejado.

Segue trecho do código que montei, se aumentar a quantidade de ocorrências na coluna ou o nome das colunas, precisa alterar vários parâmetros, além de demorar muito tempo pra rodar quando tenho muitos CPFs

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CPF': [11111111111, 22222222222],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 1': ['01/01/2021', '15/02/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 1': [24.01, 36.97],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 2': ['22/03/2021', '02/09/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 2': [54.74, 96.7],
    'Data - Ocorrencia 3': ['04/05/2021', '06/11/2022'],
    'Valor - Ocorrencia 3': [12.41, 15.85]
})
df

list_columns = df.columns[1:]
list_index = [f"{i.split(' ')[-1]:0>2} {i.split(' - ')[-2]}" for i in list_columns]

colunas_rename = dict(zip(list_columns, list_index))
df.rename(columns=colunas_rename, inplace=True)
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
for i in ['CPF']:
    column_to_move = df.pop(i)
    df.insert(0, i, column_to_move)

df_total = pd.DataFrame()
for lin in range(len(df)):
    df_to_create = df[lin:lin+1].copy()
    df_cpfs = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(1, 6, 2):
        new_df = df_to_create.iloc[:,[0, i, i+1]].copy()
        if pd.isnull(new_df.iloc[0,1]) and i > 1:
            break
        n_ocorrencia = int((i+1)/2)
        new_df['Ocorrencia'] = f'Ocorrencia {n_ocorrencia}'
        new_df.columns = ['CPF', 'Data', 'Valor','Ocorrencia']
        df_cpfs = pd.concat([df_cpfs, new_df])
    if len(df_cpfs.query('Data.notna()')) == 0:
        df_cpfs = df_cpfs[:1]
        qtd_ocorrencias = 0
    else:
        df_cpfs = df_cpfs.query('Data.notna()')
        qtd_ocorrencias = len(df_cpfs)
    df_cpfs['Qtd ocorrencias'] = qtd_ocorrencias
    df_total = pd.concat([df_total, df_cpfs])

df_total = df_total.reset_index(drop=True)
display(df_total)
```

Alguma outra ideia de como fazer isto ou alguma dica para melhorar a performance do meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alcançar o resultado esperado você vai precisar (1) aplicar a função [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) para transformar as colunas de Datas e Valores em linhas separadas. (2) Usar `.str` e [`.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) para separar as ocorrências em uma  nova coluna e finalmente (3) aplicar [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) para recriar as colunas **Data** e **Valor**

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['CPF'])

df['Ocorrencia'] = df['variable'].str.split(' - ').str[1]
df['variable'] = df['variable'].str.split(' - ').str[0]

df = df.pivot(index=['CPF','Ocorrencia'], columns='variable', values='value').reset_index()

df.head(6)
#saida:
variable    CPF Ocorrencia      Data        Valor
0   11111111111 Ocorrencia 1    01/01/2021  24.01
1   11111111111 Ocorrencia 2    22/03/2021  54.74
2   11111111111 Ocorrencia 3    04/05/2021  12.41
3   22222222222 Ocorrencia 1    15/02/2022  36.97
4   22222222222 Ocorrencia 2    02/09/2022  96.7
5   22222222222 Ocorrencia 3    06/11/2022  15.85
```

OBS: esse campo **variable** no print é só o atributo *name* das colunas e pode ser removido usando o código `df.columns.name = ''`

Comment: Olá, Terry, excelente alternativa, deu muito certo com a tabela de exemplo e vou testar na minha tabela real, muito obrigado! Marquei sua resposta como válida, atendeu muito bem o que eu precisava.